# Most idiomatic name for typescript generic index signature interface?

Tags: typescript

Is there an idiomatic name for the interface with a string index and generic type?

```
interface ___ <T> {
  [index: string]: T
}
```

Looking through stack overflow examples I've seen `StringIndexable`, `StringIndex`, `StrIndex`, `DictionaryIndex`, <del>`Map`</del>, etc.

In a current project I'm using the name `ObjectMap`. Before adding the type to another project, I'd like to know if there is a best practice.

ES6 has the `Map<K,V>` class, but even in newly written code, there are reasons to prefer an indexed object.

Is there a reason there isn't a built in name for this type? The [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) states 'string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern', but makes no suggestion of having the return type generic.

Typescript also has the [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) which can be used as `Record<string, T>`. Though the handbook describes using a union of strings for `Keys` and doesn't comment on using a catch all of `string` instead. It works, but it feels counter to stated intention of the type. The question still applies to the name of `type ___<T> = Record<string, T>`. Spelling out `Record<string, Foo>` could be the answer though`.

Is it actually idiomatic to spell out the full index type for any specific use case?

```
type Foo = any;
interface FooCollection {
    [index: string]: Foo;
}
function updateFooCollection(foos: FooCollection){}
// vs
function updateFooCollection(foos: ObjectMap<Foo>){}
```

Comment: you could call it `StringRecord` as it is bascially a `Record<string, T>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), and it's built-in. Your `FooCollection` is simply `Record<string, Foo>`. A generic `T` collection is `Record<string, T>`.

Comment: Good point, but I have remarks about this that I added to my question. As documented, doesn't *seem* like intended/idomatic usage, but idk

Comment: I would immediately understand the intention of `Record<string, T>`. And ESLint will actually [suggest using `Record<string, unknown>`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/) in a particular situation, so that's a point in favor of its usage being idiomatic.

Comment: "'- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.'," instead of `Object` or `{}`. Good reference.